# Maven does not see dependencies in local repository

Tags: java, maven, repository

My company recently got a task to fix and maintain some application written earlier by another company. We received sources and all required dependencies from that company.

I have a problem building project with Maven, because it cannot resolve a dependency which was held for some strange reason by the previous company on their own Artifactory repositories (which were held localy, apparently, on developers PCs).

This required dependency is present in my local repository on what I hope is the proper path. On every build attempt Maven wants to connect to custom repositories and fails.

Running with -offline flag does not help, as it states that this dependency was not downloaded before. Running custom local Artifactory repository does not help to solve the problem either (I did not try to do it, but a colleague before did and told me it's not working). I've tried to install .jar file to local repository using Maven install:install-file, which succeded, but did not help.

What else should I try to do in order to build this project?

Comment: take a look at which path is maven install is installing this jar, and compare it with your dependent project's maven build logs. And be sure your settings.xml file is right, since it's trying to connect some other repositories there can be an error. And also as last check this project's pom.xml there can be some custom repositories in it. Just remove them.

Comment: Can you just post a snippet of your pom.xml with the artifact that is in error ? Can you check if the artifact is in the right directory in your .m2 repository (locally) ?